# Access lastInsertId variable outside a function

Tags: php, pdo, lastinsertid

so I have a simple code here that will insert a data and will return the `last inserted id`. Here is my code:

```
function newUser($fname, $age) {
  global $newUserLastID;
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', '');
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $data = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (fname, age) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $data->execute(array($fname, $age));
  $newUserLastID = $conn->lastInsertId('accounts');
}
```

And what I wanted to do is to run the function and get the global variable like:

```
newUser('JohnDoe', '22');
$someVar = $newUserLastID;
```

My problem is whenever I run this code, my `CLI` always crashes. Is there a way to fix this? I also get this on production server. I'm not getting any error besides this.

[image]
[image]

(by just running the function, my CLI crashes)

Comment: Any error messages to report?

Comment: "crashes" means what *exactly* ?

Comment: @Tim, that's my problem.. I'm not getting any.

Comment: `$conn` looks out of scope

Comment: sigh, post all the code or none, next time

Comment: @Dagon, I added a screenshot

Comment: ouch windows .. no idea

Comment: Are you positive `$someVar = $newUserLastID; ` is what's crashing it? if you comment out that line, it doesn't crash?

Comment: No it isn't, just by running the function my CLI crashes @sqram

Comment: @FewFlyBy Your best bet, and first step, should be to run the body of the function line by line in the CLI and see which line crashes it.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use sequences so you shouldn't be passing anything into `$conn->lastInsertId()`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return the new ID instead of using a global variable? So, the last line of your function would be:

`return $newUserLastID`

Then, when you call the function, you'd instead assign it to a variable, like this:

`$myNewId = newUser('JohnDoe', '22');`

I don't know if this is the cause of your error, but it might be a place to start.